# Is a countable set empty if last element is zero?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume I have a set $S=\{1,\ldots,N\}$, where $N$ is an integer. In my case, $N$ can be zero or non-zero, depending on situation.

If $N=0$, does it automatically mean that $S=\emptyset$? I feel like it should, but would like to be sure. Thanks in advance for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In the context of the natural numbers, if we write $S=\{1,\ldots,N\}$, then we mean really $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid 1\leq x\leq N\}$. If $N<1$, then there are no such $x$ and the set is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if $S$ is informally defined by $S = \{1,\ldots,N\}$, then if $N = 1$ this means $S = \{1\}$ and if $N = 0$ this means $S = \emptyset$.